# jQuery Validation on CC Month and Year in separate selects

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm working with jQuery validate and I've been trying to solve the CC month and CC year being in two separate drop downs. The cardNumber validates fine, but the month and year will give "invalid" on loss of focus, but never validates once it's corrected.

Here's the form:

```
<form name="form2" id="ccTest" method="post" action="">
            <label for="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="required" size="25" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" autocomplete="off" />


            <label for="cardExpMonth">Expiration Date</label>

            <select name="cardExpMonth" id="cardExpMonth" size="1">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select> 

            <select name="cardExpYear" id="cardExpYear" size="1">
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
```

And here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#ccTest').on("change", function(){
            $('#ccTest').validate({
            rules: {
                cardNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    creditcard: true,
                    minlength: 13,
                    maxlength: 16      
                },
                cardExpYear: {
                    CCExp: { 
                        formMonth: #cardExpMonth,
                        formYear: #cardExpYear
                    }
                }

            }
            });
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("CCExp", function(value, element, params) {
                var minMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
                var minYear = new Date().getFullYear();

                var formMonth = $(params.cardExpMonth);
                var formYear = $(params.cardExpYear);

                var month = parseInt(formMonth.val(), 10);
                var year = parseInt(formYear.val(), 10);


                if ((formYear > minYear) || ((formYear === minYear) && (formMonth >= minMonth))) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        }, "Your Credit Card Expiration date is invalid.");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. If there's something that could work better I would be happy to look at it.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#ccTest').on("change", function(){
                $('#ccTest').validate({
                rules: {
                    cardNumber: {
                        required: true,
                        creditcard: true,
                        minlength: 13,
                        maxlength: 16      
                    },
                    cardExpYear: {
                        required: true,
                        CCExp: { 
                            formMonth: "#cardExpMonth",
                            formYear: "#cardExpYear"
                        }
                    }

                }
                });


                $.validator.addMethod("CCExp", function(value, element, params) {
                        var minMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
                        var minYear = new Date().getFullYear();

                        var formMonth = $("#cardExpMonth").val();
                        var formYear = $("#cardExpYear").val();



                        var month = parseInt(formMonth);
                        var year = parseInt(formYear);

                        if ((year > minYear) || ((year === minYear) && (month >= minMonth))) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                }, "Invalid Expiration Date!");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/khadeerali26/ydftr9xc/3/

```
    $(function() {
      $('#startDate').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
          $("#endDate").datepicker("destroy");
          $("#endDate").val("");
          var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
          var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
               
          $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
          $('#endDate').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            maxDate: new Date(year, month-1, 1),
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            
              var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
              var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                
              $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
```